# Optimized way to read files based on file names in directory using python

Tags: python

I have a directory with images I want to read. Each image is named as numbers (0.jpg, 1.jpg.. 10000.jpg). What is the optimized way to read images in a range and store the output in respective directories.

One approach is to use count and read/process accordingly.

```
img_dir = "/path/to/images"
op_dir_1 = "/path/to/output/dir_1"
op_dir_2 = "/path/to/output/dir_2"
op_dir_3 = "/path/to/output/dir_3"
count = 0
for img_path in tqdm(sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(img_dir, "*.jpg")))):
    if count < 100:
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # do processing and store output in op_dir_1
        count += 1
    if count > 99 and count < 150:
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # do processing and store output in op_dir_2
        count += 1
    if count > 149 and count < 200:
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        # do processing and store output in op_dir_3
        count += 1
```

Is there an optimized way to this, just iterate the directory for the images I need (in a range) and read. By using the file name (Since its numbered) instead of count?

Comment: What makes you think that incrementing `count` is so sub-optimal? The only thing you'll be able to do here is use a dictionary to make your code DRY (don't repeat yourself) but it's I/O bound from disk, so there's not a lot you can do

Comment: not much you can do to optimize read that's not already being cached by disk. closest you can try is parallel reads and process with cv2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52162421/10703473

Comment: Wouldn't the for loop run till the last image in the directory, what if there are 1 million images? That's why I thought it was sub-optimal. isn't it?

Comment: It's only sub-optimal if you don't need to read 1 million images.

Comment: yeah the directory might have 1 million images, but I only need to read and process first 200 images for a sample set. (range 1: 0-99, range 2: 100-149, range 3: 150-199)